# help me set up drivers to my Epson printer

Tags: drivers, package-management, printing, scanner, epson

I have Ubuntu installed on my computer but I honestly don't know a thing about running programs off of this OS. I'm trying to set up a printer to this computer through a USB connection for the ease of set up, although I would prefer to have a wireless connection. (If someone can help with that, I would really appreciate it, but one thing at a time.) I've gone on to the Epson website and tried to download the drivers for this OS but first it gives me a notice:

> In order to install these drivers, you need to install LSB package
> (version 3.2 or later) beforehand.
>
> Ubuntu:
>
> ```
> apt-get install lsb
> ```

which I have no idea what it means. I did some research and tried to type into the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install lsb 3.2
```

The response I get is:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host
```

then it asks me for a password and after I enter this, I get

```
Reading package listing... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no package: Header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/is.arcive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could bot be parsed or opened.
```

Like I said before, I don't know how to run this OS, someone else installed it for me. I would really just like to know exactly how to install these drivers, exactly how to, like step-by-step (dumb it down, like a 101 class.) My printer is called Epson Workforce WF-3640.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include a link to the instructions from Epson that you're referring in it?

Comment: The model name of your printer and the output of `lsusb` (with the printer plugged in and running) would also be valuable information.

Comment: solution is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/763157/ubuntu-16-04-installing-epson-driver-fails-on-lsb-3-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there are multiple issues visible from the information you provide:

1. `sudo: unable to resolve host` – see [Error message when I run sudo: unable to resolve host (none)](/q/59458/175814)
2. Malformed Apt repository lists – see [How do I fix a “Problem with MergeList” or “status file could not be parsed” error when trying to do an update?](/q/30072/175814)

After you fixed those (preferably in the above order), we can address the task at hand properly: The instruction to install the package `lsb` via the command `apt-get install lsb` means pretty much this:

1. Open a command interpreter terminal, e. g. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Type in `sudo`, a space and the aforementioned command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install lsb
   ```

   Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to have the shell interpreter execute the command.
3. `sudo` (**s**uper-**u**ser **do**) elevates the privileges of the subsequent command, provided that the system allows it to do so. If your user account is in the administrative group, you'll be granted "super-user" privileges, provided you can authenticate yourself with your account password.
4. `apt` will then try to install the package `lsb`, as you have asked it. If you want to verify the package version before installing it, you can use

   ```
   apt-cache show lsb
   ```

   and look for the line staring with `Version:` in its output. You don't need elevated privileges to run this command, since it doesn't alter any system files.

Comment: Thank you for you help! Now I'm trying to install the driver given to me by the Epson website (http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule). First off, which file do I download? I assume one found here: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=43353&DSCCHK=9f26e5cbd41612f9e38f91537c63c82d18c401e9
second, once I download this file, how to I install it?

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I actually figured it out! I can't tell you how much I appreciate you're help!!! :)

Comment: @Maya: Could you please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) (or [edit] my answer, if you prefer) to share your solution, so future readers can profit from it? I'll vote for it, if you ping me and it's any good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Epson driver from a deb file from Epson site.

You will get an error message regarding lsb.

Then run `sudo apt-get install -f` and all will be resolved if you are connected to internet.