# Ubuntu 16.04 installing Epson driver fails on LSB >= 3.2

Tags: printing, 16.04, epson

Automatic installation of Epson print WP-4015 Ubuntu 16.04 never finish... installation freeze.

If I download latest drivers from epson.net, I can't install DEB package, because of APT writes me that required LSB >= 3.2. But I have installed LSB installed in higher version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lsb3.2 Epson printer error in Xenial](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760974/lsb3-2-epson-printer-error-in-xenial)

Comment: @fkraiem I strongly disagree since the other one doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 24):

solution is easy, **at first**

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr
```

after that search on your computer Printers after having connected the printer click on Add and after click on the model of your printer and follow installation

Comment: You just saved my life sir...

Comment: Sir you deserve a cookie, all this lsb hassle which was not even needed ... Thank you!

Comment: Legend, only thing I've found that works