# How do I install Epson ET-2550 driver where lsb <=3.2 is required?

Tags: drivers, software-installation, printing

I recently bought a new printer `Epson ET-2550` and downloaded the driver via the official Epson website at http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule.

When I tried to install the driver I received the error message:

> Dependency is not satisfiable: lsb (>= 3.2)

even though my lsb is 4.1!

I have tried several fixes, including typing the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr
```

As recommended here: [Ubuntu 16.04 installing Epson driver fails on LSB >= 3.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763157/ubuntu-16-04-installing-epson-driver-fails-on-lsb-3-2)

Could someone talk me through how to fix this?
I am a fair novice user so simple language would be appreciated.
The driver I am trying to install is titled:

```
epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.10-1lsb3.2_i386.deb
```

Many thanks

Comment: Please copy ans paste the full error message into your post.

Comment: Run `sudo apt install -f` and the `lsb` packages will install.

Comment: It seems a all-in-one package has just been released at http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Answer (score 1):

### **UPDATE for Ubuntu 19.10**

I realized that with the generic EPSON ET Series drives it doesn't print correctly (prints ASCII carachters :(), so you must modify the Make and Model from "Local Raw Printer" to "Epson Expression ET-2550 EcoTank - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.3.1"

### **UPDATE for Ubuntu 18.10**

I had problems with the configuration in Ubuntu 18.10 with CUPS Server.

1. Enter into the CUPS server Web (http://localhost:631/admin/)
2. Look for the Option "Add New Printer" and add your Ubuntu User and Pass
3. Here there are several Options --> Select the *Driverless* one (in order to have it by the Hostname instead by the IP) "EPSON ET-2550 Series (EPSON ET-2550 Series (driverless))" (I have checked also "Share in Network")
4. Select the Model (if NOT listed, install the Printer Drivers, 1st direct from Ubuntu "lsb", if doesn't work download from the EPSON Page)
5. Try to Print something

**IMPORTANT:** If you can not print anything probably you have a problem with the .local ending in the Hostname (in my case EPSON14562B)

1. Go to the Printers Menu --> Additional Settings in Ubuntu Settings
2. Go to Properties of the Added Printer
3. Replace ".local" with ".lan" (or remove it) from the Device Address: ipp://EPSON14562B **.local** :631/ipp/print --> ipp://EPSON14562B **.lan** :631/ipp/print or directly ipp://EPSON14562B:631/ipp/print
4. Print again :)

### **ORIGINAL Post for Ubuntu 16.10**

I have the same All-In-One Printer ET-2550, and those are the steps I followed to **configure with the WLAN connection** through my Home Router in Ubuntu 16.10 64bits.

1. First of all connect the Printer to your Home Router using the Display and the Assistant Configurator from the Printer.
2. Insert the Local IP Address in a Browser (i.e. Firefox) to check that it is the correct IP (you can check it in the Router), in my case:
   http://192.168.178.33 (you can also use the Printer Hostname i.e. http://epson14562b:631)
3. Copy it! We will need it later in Ubuntu Configurator

Now You can go to Ubuntu:

4. System Properties-->Printer-->Add a New Printer
5. In the Network Printer Drop Down, wait till Appears your Printer EPSON (with IP 192.168.178.33 in my case) and Select it and press continue.
6. Follow the Driver Assistant, choosing your EPSON printer from the list.

If your EPSON Model doesn't appear you have to Install the Drivers first and go to Point 4 again.

7. Test Print a Page, in my case didn't work!
8. If this doesn't work change the URL of the Printer (in the Printer Properties) for this one (Printer IP + 631 Port): https://192.168.178.33:631/ipp/print (better solution use the Printer hostname ipp://EPSON14562B:631/ipp/print)
9. Test Print a Page, in my case NOW works! You can print from any place of your Home :)

You can set a fixed IP to your Printer in your Router configuration in order to avoid probably change of the IP. (Not necessary if you use the hostname of the Printer)

The Scanner works perfectly with the Application "Simple Scan".

### **To Download the EPSON drivers**

Try to configure first without installing any EPSON driver.
If the Scanner or/and the Printer are not correctly detected then Install Drivers

**Printer**

```
sudo apt-get install lsb
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr
```

If you want the Epson "Printer Utility" download the .deb Package from:

```
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule
```

Install them the way you prefer!

**Scanner**

```
http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php
```

Download Ubuntu 16.10 64bits package.

```
https://download2.ebz.epson.net/imagescanv3/ubuntu/latest1/deb/x64/imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.10-1.0.0.x64.deb.tar.gz
```

Extract it and execute the "install.sh" File.

Comment: Thank you Nothor, this has worked!  It is very much appreciated.

Comment: Wait, it only allows me to print a test page.  Still can't print full documents. I guess I still need the Epson driver which I still cannot download.

Comment: I mean, I can still download the driver, but still get the same error message when I try to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the driver for ET-14000 that couldn't install on my computer (same error message) but then I tried with the other .deb file (64bits) available on the epson driver page of my printer:

```
epson-printer-utility_1.0.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
```

(page http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=FR&CN2=&DSCMI=54516&DSCCHK=e33a118ab592a76ec51b8134c20ea22b87ea2967)

I hope this helps even if I did not manage to go further.

The .deb installed correctly this time, but I haven't managed to install the printer. I cannot find it in the list of available models. And the only available alternative in CUPS would be to provide a PPD file. Not a .deb